# Index of a derivative operator on a circle

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, fourier-series

Let $D: C^{1}(S^{1}) \rightarrow C(S^{1})$ be an operator defined as $D(f)=f'$.

I would like to find its index (on the road proving that it's a Fredholm operator).

First, if $f \in ker(D)$, then $f$ is constant almost everywhere on a circle.

What goes about cokernel, its dimension equal the dimension of a kernel of an adjoint operator, by Riez-Markov-Kakutani theorem, the adjoint is $T(f(x)) = \int_{S^{1}}{f'(x) \mu(dx))}$, $\mu$ is some Radon measure.

The claim is that the index equals 0, the both the $ker(D)$ and $ker(D^{*})$ have the same dimension. It's clear that $ker(D) \subset ker(D^{*})$, but also it is true that there is no inverse inclusion -- but still this does not affect the dimension property.

Probably, the idea is to use the Fourier expansion on the cirlce, $$f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}{c_{n} e^{inz}}$$ then $$f'(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}{in c_{n} e^{inz}}$$ but this no seems to be very benefitial so far.

What are the possible approaches to pose the problem?

Any sort of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, one can avoid Fourier theory by identifying the spaces $$C(S^1)=\left\{f\in C([0,1],\mathbb C) \ | \ f(0)=f(1)\right\}$$ and $$C^1(S^1)=\left\{f\in C^1([0,1],\mathbb C) \ | \ f(0)=f(1) \text{ and } f'(0)=f'(1)\right\}.$$

In this way, you get that $f\in \ker(D)$ if and only if $f$ is constant.

Moreover, one can easily notice that $$C(S^1)=Im(D)\oplus \mathbb C$$ where $\mathbb C$ represents the complex vector space of constant functions on $S^1$.

Indeed,

- If $f\in Im(D)\cap \mathbb C$ then there exists $g\in C^1(S^1)$ such that $f=g'$ and $f\equiv C$ thus $g(t)=Ct+D$. However $g$ must satisfy $g(0)=g(1)$ and $g'(0)=g'(1)$ hence $g$ is the constant function and $f\equiv 0$.
- Let $f\in C(S^1)$, one can define the function $g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb C$ by $$g(t)=\int_0^tf(s)ds-t\int_0^1f(s)ds.$$
  $g$ is continuously differentiable and $$\left\{\begin{array}{l}g(0)=0=g(1) \\ g'(0)=f(0)-\displaystyle  \int_0^1f(s)ds \\ g'(1)=f(1)-\displaystyle  \int_0^1f(s)ds\end{array}\right.$$
  thus $g$ belongs to $C^1(S^1)$ since $f(0)=f(1)$ and $$\forall t\in [0,1], \ f=\underbrace{g'}_{\in Im(D)}+\underbrace{\int_0^1f(s)ds}_{\in \mathbb C}.$$

As a consequence, $D$ has a finite dimensional cokernel isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ which means that $D$ is a fredholm operator with index $$ind(D)=\dim \ker(D)-\dim \text{coker}(D)=0.$$